# Passing Cookie as a Request Header - SSO JMeter

Tags: testing, cookies, jmeter, single-sign-on, performance-testing

I'm doing load testing for an application using JMeter for which I need to perform SSO authentication. I have to send a cookie as request header like I it is done below:

[image]

I have the value that I need to send, which I have extracted using Regular Expression Extractor on a previous Request. How can I achieve this?

I am using JMeter 3.1

Comment: Are you trying to send additional cookie values apart from the ones already existing, manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a [cookie manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. Extract cookie with your Regular Expression Extractor to some variable (e.g. my_cookie)
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and use this code

   `import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
    import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;

    CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("SESSION_COOKIE_NAME", "${my_cookie}", "${servername}", "/", false, 0);
    manager.add(cookie);`

More info for CookieManager class [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/CookieManager.html)

Comment: Worked fine. Thanks!!

Comment: is it okay?  
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("Cookie", "${my_cookie}", "pixel.quantserve.com", "/", false, 0);

Comment: Yes, it is.But it is better to use variables like ${servername}

Answer (score 0):

You basically don't need to extract anything, just add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan and it will automatically handle cookies.

If you need certain cookie value to use it somewhere else you can add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
```

and restart JMeter to pick the property up. Once done you will be able to refer cookie value as `${COOKIE_mc}` where required.

See [Using the HTTP Cookie Manager in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) for more information.